# How to get emails that clicked company links? Mailchimp

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I want to get email addresses for those who clicked the links in the campaign.
I am using GET /reports/{campaign_id}/email-activity from documentation

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/

I understand how to get emails or activity. But how to get only emails who clicked links in company?

```
$curlopt_url = "https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/4d92ce9489/email-activity?count=400&fields=emails.email_address,emails.activity";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Use https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/members/ instead to retrieve the contacts who clicked on specific links of specific campaigns.

Comment: thanks, this way looks better than mine, but what if i don't know the link id? or a lot of links in the campaign? can be obtained without specifying the id?

Comment: and where i can find link id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the route [`GET /reports/{campaign_id}/click-details`](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/) to obtain informations about the links of your campaign, returning something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1550
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Request-Id: 0d2a23c7-b54a-47ca-adc7-95dff2fd4dcc
Link: <https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Collection.json>; rel="describedBy"
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 14:56:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


{
  "urls_clicked": [
    {
      "id": "54debc3673",
      "url": "http://inspiration.mailchimp.com?goal=0_57afe96172-42694e9e57-[LIST_EMAIL_ID]&mc_cid=42694e9e57&mc_eid=[UNIQID]",
      "total_clicks": 0,
      "click_percentage": 0,
      "unique_clicks": 0,
      "unique_click_percentage": 0,
      "last_click": "",
      "campaign_id": "42694e9e57",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "parent",
          "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details",
          "method": "GET",
          "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Collection.json"
        },
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details/54debc3673",
          "method": "GET",
          "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Instance.json"
        },
        {
          "rel": "members",
          "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details/54debc3673/members",
          "method": "GET",
          "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Members/Collection.json"
        },
        {
          "rel": "campaign",
          "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/42694e9e57",
          "method": "GET",
          "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Instance.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "campaign_id": "42694e9e57",
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "parent",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/Instance.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Collection.json"
    }
  ],
  "total_items": 1
}
```

Identify the specific link(s) you want in them then use the route [`GET /reports/{campaign_id}/click-details/{link_id}/members`](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/members/) to obtain the contacts who have clicked it/them, returning eg:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 498
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Request-Id: e9979709-0ce6-4c82-877f-0e77a6f850be
Link: <https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Members/Collection.json>; rel="describedBy"
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 15:15:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


{
  "members": [
    {
      "email_id": "62eeb292278cc15f5817cb78f7790b08",
      "email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com",
      "clicks": 42,
      "campaign_id": "42694e9e57",
      "url_id": "54debc3673",
      "list_id": "4ca5becb8d"
    }
  ],
  "campaign_id": "42694e9e57",
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "parent",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details/54debc3673",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Instance.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/42694e9e57/click-details/54debc3673/members",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/ClickDetails/Members/Collection.json"
    }
  ],
  "total_items": 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
$emailsClicked = array();
foreach ($row in json_decode($result))
{
  if ($row->activity->action == 'click')
    $emailsClicked[] = $row->email_address;
}
print_r($emailsClicked);
```

I was not able to try this code. If it does not work, please provide a var_dump($result);